# Calculating Min and Max Across fields while skipping Zeros

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, address

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 here. I have a streets layer that has address ranges in the fields FromLeft, ToLeft, FromRight, and ToRight. I am trying to create a street index csv that has the low and high values for each street. I'm trying to calculate the min and max values across the 4 fields and calculate those into 2 new fields called MIN and MAX.

I used `min( !FromLeft!, !FromRight!, !ToLeft!, !ToRight!)` to get the minimum values.

The only thing is that some streets have 0 in one or more of these 4 fields. I would like to skip the value 0 from this calculation and only consider non-zero numbers.

Can this be done using the field calculator?

All my fields are LONGs.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there are easier ways, but here's one using Python.

1. In the Field Calculator window, select the *Python* parser
2. Check *Show Codeblock*
3. The Pre-logic Script code defines a method that returns only values greater than 0.

```
def greater_than_0 (value):
    return value > 0
```

4. The code for the MIN field is

```
min (filter (greater_than_0, [ !FromLeft!, !FromRight!, !ToLeft!, !ToRight! ]))
```

Note that this code will fail if *all* fields contain 0 values. If you have those, you may want to make a feature selection to exclude those records first

Here's a screenshot (Never mind my fieldnames, I used a scrap shapefile)

[image: Field calculator]

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: I can't get this code to work in ArcGIS Pro (python 9.3). Is there a difference? It seems to me the field calculator doesn't like this use of python's filter function? As soon as I add the 'filter', I get an error that says "No function was found with the name 'min' (even though the  'min' function works just fine when I don't employ 'filter').